# Google indexing duplicate page content with Page #### in post title and /page-2 in permalink instead of the ones I set

Tags: posts, pages, seo, duplicates, google-search

I'm hoping someone familiar with this problem can help me. I have a WordPress site with thousands of posts, and Google is indexing pages that look like this:

mysite.com/page/1

mysite.com/page/2

mysite.com/page/3

Each of these are showing a post title in the SERPs like this: Page 3423 - My Site Name ... When you click the link, it is going to a specific post that SHOULD be indexing with the permalink I set (not the page number permalink above), and the post title that I set (not the Page 3423).

About half of my SERPs look like this, and the other half look correct with the right permalink and post title. I don't know what setting I have wrong. I have already set Google XML Sitemaps to not index categories. I've also checked with my theme and a couple other plugins, and none of them are doing it.

The more research I do on this, the more I'm getting confused. Thoughts? Keep in mind I have a BASIC understanding of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

try the Yoast seo plugin. In the past few weeks, I tried switching to SEO audit plugins, most of them available options like declaring to search engines that No index pages / page2, page / n ... I turned Back to Yoast Seo, Yoast Seo even in the free version, has a pre-installed token with a search engine for pages from page2, Canonical, on the first page.